# How to format list in text file?

Tags: python, text, text-files

I have a text file like below

> Mo, M, 15,
>
> Jen, F, 14

My code below replaces the age for 'Mo'

```
newAge = "20"
result = ""
with open("file.txt") as f:
for line in f:
   if line.lower().startswith( "mo," ):
       list = line.split() 
       list[2] = str( newAge )
       line = ", ".join( list )
   result += line + '\n'
f = open("file.txt", 'w') 
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

How ever the file afterwards look like

> [,',,M,,o,,M,,2,,0,,',]

How to I format it to look like the:

> Mo, M, 20,

Comment: you may want to specify the string to split with. i.e.  list = line.split(', ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this instead:

```
newAge = "20"
result = ""
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.lower().startswith( "mo," ):
            list = line.split() 
            list[2] = newAge
            line = ''
            for element in list:
                line += str(element)
                line += ', '
        result += line + '\n'
with open('file.txt', 'w') as inf:
    inf.write(result)
```

If you're particular about the space at the end of the last element, you could even do:

```
newAge = "20"
result = ""
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.lower().startswith( "mo," ):
            list = line.split() 
            list[2] = newAge
            line = ''
            for index, element in enumerate(list):
                line += str(element)
                if not index is len(list) -1:
                    line += ', '
                else:
                    line += ','
        result += line + '\n'
with open('file.txt', 'w') as inf:
    inf.write(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for both reading and writing the file. Below is a tested example.

```
newAge = ' 20'
result = []
with open('file.txt','rb') as fin, open('file_out.txt','wb') as fou:
    cr = csv.reader(fin)
    cw = csv.writer(fou)
    for line in cr:
        if line[0].lower() == "mo":
            line[2] = newAge
        cw.writerow(line)
```

Comment: `csv` module is a life saver especially with large data dumps (at least from my experience)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Chinny84

Answer (score 0):

like @azalea mentioned, use .split(', '). Also, you should only use the newline character on strings you build because the existing strings already contain the new line.

```
newAge = "20"
result = ""
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.lower().startswith("mo"):
            list = line.split(', ')
            list[2] = str(newAge)
            line = ", ".join(list) + '\n'
        result += line
f = open("file2.txt", 'w')
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You split the line by space...then you should join it by space!

```
newAge = "20"
result = ""
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       if line.lower().startswith( "mo," ):
           list = line.split() 
           list[2] = str( newAge )
           line = " ".join( list )+"\n"
       result += line
f = open("file.txt", 'w') 
f.write(result)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using keeping it simple . Just use the string module. 
You can use it in this way.

```
import string

toFind = '15'
newAge = '20'
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    text[0] = string.replace(text[0],toFind,newAge)
with open('file.txt','w') as f:
    for item in text:
        f.write(item)
```

I hope this helps!